# Generating permutations in python

Tags: python

I want to implement a function, generate_perm(m,n), where it takes two arguments, one is for numbers to permutate (m) and second is to what the sum of the permutation must equate to (n).

```
def generate_perm(m,n):
    '''
     implement this
    '''
    return
```

`generate_perm(2,5)` should output

```
[(1,4), (2,3), (3,2) (4,1)]
```

and

`generate_perm(3,5)` should output:

```
[(1,1,3), (1,2,2), (1,3,1), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), (3,1,1)]
```

EDIT
i havent gotten far

```
def generate_permutations(m, n):
    all = []
    cur = [0 for i in range(m)]
    len_perm = m*2
    while True:
        for i in range(m):
            if cur[i] == 0: # initial case
                if i != m-1:
                    cur[i] = 1
                else:
                    cur[i] = n-m

        all.append(cur)
        if len(all) >= len_perm:
            break
    return all
```

Comment: You are supposed to submit your attempts so far.

Comment: Have a look at [``itertools.permutations``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for a start.

Comment: @coldspeed this is not a homework. im not even in school

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i would like to do this without using any liberaries which already calculate permuations

Comment: @ealeon, any reasonable reasons?

Comment: @taras i am practicing coding for my personal fun ie there is no benefit for me to actually get the func implemented other than to learn the algorithm so if i use some library to accomplish that, then i wouldn't really learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple recursive approach without any libraries:

```
def perm(m, n):
  if m == 1:  # base case
    return [(n,)]
  perms = []
  for s in range(1, n):  # combine possible start values: 1 through n-1 ...
    for p in perm(m-1, n-s):  # ... with all appropriate smaller perms 
      perms.append((s,) + p)
  return perms

>>> perm(1, 5)
[(5,)]
>>> perm(2, 5)
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
>>> perm(3, 5)
[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: thank you! this seems to work. so this would be O(n^m)?

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. One would have to solve the appropriate recurrence equation :( the data structures used here also aren't optimal, e.g. `(s,) + p` itself is `O(len(p))` for tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a list `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`

You can get all the permutations with `itertools.permutations`

```
p = itertools.permutations(list(range(1,6)),2)
```

and then filter them

```
my_elems = [el for el in p if sum(el) == 5]
```

outputs

```
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Looking at the second example you give, I think what you want is a `product`, not `permutations`:

```
p = itertools.product(list(range(1,6)),repeat=3)

my_elems = [el for el in p if sum(el) == 5]

#[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1)]
```

and which works also for the first case.